# Log4j2 Database insert in Websphere?

Tags: java, configuration, websphere, jndi, log4j2

In my local,

I created an log4j2.xml to config like that.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <configuration status="OFF">
      <appenders>
        <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->

        <FastFile name="AsyncFastFile" fileName="${sys:logFilename}" 
                  immediateFlush="false" append="true">
          <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>test %m %m %ex%n</pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
        </FastFile>

    <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="mytablename">
          <DriverManager url="jdbc:oracle:thin:ORCL_USERNAME/PASS@//MYSERVERNAME:PORTNO/DBNAME" />
          <Column name="KEY1" pattern="%X{sayi1}" />
          <Column name="KEY2" pattern="%X{sayi2}" />
          </JDBC>

        <JDBC name="databaseAppenderJNDI" tableName="mytablename">
      <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/logWS" />
      <Column name="KEY1" pattern="%X{sayi1}" />
      <Column name="KEY2" pattern="%X{sayi2}" />
     </JDBC>  


      </appenders>

      <loggers>


        <!-- pattern layout actually uses location, so we need to include it -->
        <asyncLogger name="ASYNC" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </asyncLogger>

 <!-- pattern layout actually uses location, so we need to include it -->
        <asyncLogger name="ASYNCwithJNDI" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="databaseAppenderJNDI"/>
        </asyncLogger>


        <root level="info" includeLocation="true">
          <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </root>

      </loggers>
    </configuration>
```

I can insert logs to text file and DB by switching loggername in my java class which I call log function. There no problem in my local.

In Webshere server,

I call a web service for logging. I am using same config file and same java codes which calls log function. I can insert logs to a file but I can't insert logs to database. I tried both driverManager url and JNDI. But nothing changed. In two ways, I can't insert log to DB and program doesn't throw any error in try-catch. So I can't find problem where is.

Note : There is no problem at JNDI url and drivermanager url. Because I can perfectly use these urls in different webservice in wepshere. Also I can insert log to Database in my local with same codes.

Note : There is no problem to insert logs to txt file. only DB insertion is problem in Websphere server. So there isn't problem at config file classpath.

For your info, I am using oracle DB but the problem isn't about DB.
I trace network packages in server and I realize that web service don't send any package to DB. Packages don't reach to DB.

How can I solve this problem?

THX.

Answer (score 0):

Please report this in the log4j2 issue tracker so that the log4j team can look at it.

Comment: Thx Remko. I do that. you can follow the problem by this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/LOG4J2-442